# how to extract line from a word2vec file?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have created a word2vec file and I want to extract only the line at position [0]

## this is the word2vec file

`` `36 16
Activity 0.013954502 0.009596351 -0.0002082094 -0.029975398 -0.0244055 -0.001624907 0.01995442 0.0050479663 -0.011549354 -0.020344704 -0.0113901375 -0.010574887 0.02007604 -0.008582828 0.030914625 -0.009170294
DATABASED%GWC%5 0.022193532 0.011890317 -0.018219836 0.02621059 0.0029900416 0.01779779 -0.026217759 0.0070709535 -0.021979155 0.02609082 0.009237218 -0.0065825963 -0.019650755 0.024096865 -0.022521153 0.014374277
DATABASED%GWC%7 0.021235622 -0.00062567473 -0.0045315344 0.028400827 0.016763352 0.02893731 -0.013499333 -0.0037113864 -0.016281538 0.004078895 0.015604254 -0.029257657 0.026601797 0.013721668 0.016954066 -0.026421601` ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glove_model["Activity"]` should get you its vector representation from the loaded model. This is because `glove_model` is an object of type  `KeyedVectors` and you can use key value to index into it.